# XML attributes without spaces

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I have used JAXB to create a class for the following schema (used in a webservice):

```
<xs:complexType name="ExceptionType">
        <xs:attribute name="errorCode" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="outcomeType" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                    <xs:enumeration value="rejectFile"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="rejectSubmission"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="continue"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

Though the actual XML they will send is

```
<Exception errorCode="1503"outcomeType="continue">
```

(with no space with "1503" and outcomeType).

Right now, I'm replacing `<Exception errorCode="(\d*)"outcomeType` with `<Exception errorCode="\1" outcomeType` in the whole XML response before feeding it to JAXB unmarshaller and it works, but I wonder if some other XML responses will have this "bug".
Is there an easier way have JAXB accept XML tags with this `attr1="value"attr2` bug? Or maybe using some custom XMLFilterImpl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an easier way have JAXB accept XML tags with this attr1="value"attr2 bug?

No, because this isn't a bug.

XML containing `attr1="value"attr2` aren't well-formed, thus JAXB cannot parse it and will throw an exception indicating a fatal, non-recoverable error.

If you expect *XML-ish* data of this kind and you have no control over it (you receive it from a third party), then your solution *seems* OK. However, if I was you I would contact this third party and tell them that they're spouting out invalid XML and that isn't too professional.

An alternative to replacing strings with regular expressions could be something like this (but this isn't exactly easy):

```
public String toWellFormed(String xml) throws IOException, SAXException {             
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(xml);                                                 

  XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();                                     
  reader.setContentHandler(null);                                                            
  reader.setErrorHandler(null);                                                              

  boolean threw = true;                                                                      
  while (threw)                                                                              
    try {                                                                                    
      reader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(sb.toString())));                        
      threw = false;                                                                         
    } catch (SAXParseException ex) {                                                         
      if (ex.getMessage().contains("must be followed by either attribute specifications")) {
        threw = true;
        int line = ex.getLineNumber();                                                       
        int column = ex.getColumnNumber();                                                   
        sb.insert(line * column - 1, ' ');                                                                                                            
      } else                                                                                 
        throw ex;                                                                            
    }                                                                                        

  return sb.toString();                                                                      
}                       

String malformedXml = "<test a='a'b='b'c='c'/>";  
String wellFormedXml = toWellFormed(malformedXml);
"<test a='a'b='b'c='c'/>".equals(wellFormedXml);
```

JAXB's `Unmarshaller` should be able to handle `wellFormedXml` after the process.

If replacing stuff with regular expressions is good enough, because your data doesn't contain too much stuff to search for and contains only the particular formatting error you've described, then don't use my solution of course, but if you expect more formatting error you could use something like this.

Notice, that I explicitly set the reader's error and content handler to `null`. This is because given a malformed XML they're never called; the reader will fail early, because this is a fatal, non-recoverable error. This is of course very bad for us, because if the document contains 10 errors like you've described, then my method parses the XML 10 times, until it founds every error. I'm not aware of an XML parser in the JDK, that would report formatting errors and continue parsing (reporting every error during the process).

Using a *proper* `ErrorHandler` you could handle warnings and errors gracefully, however *fatal errors* could not be handled even with an `ErrorHandler` (after its `fatalError` method gets called, processing stops).

Using an `XMLFilter` implementation wouldn't help you either, because if you simply use the default `XMLFilterImpl` class that forwards all of its calls to a delegate `XMLReader` then you would face the same problem as before: on the first error, processing stops. As a matter of fact, if you want to implement something, then implement the `XMLReader` interface directly (`XMLFilter` only adds the `setParent` and `getParent` method—bad design if you ask me). But implementing an `XMLReader` that can parse malformed XML is probably going to be tedious.

Comment: I'll accept this one as the answer since it's a better workaround than my current one. Though I won't be using it as the current stream contains multiple XML documents and I already have a custom filter to split them up so JAXB processes them properly which results in wrong line and column numbers. Plus, there could be multiple ExceptionType elements, all containing this bug, which would require a loop to fix all of them which is a big performance hit compared to just quickly replacing every match. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's an invalid xml (no space between attr value and next attr) and the parser will always fail. I think you will have to manage it the way you are currently doing or else correct it in the source itself.

Comment: Correcting the source was the first try I did, as it seemed they would be thankful to fix such a bug, but they refused to acknowledge it, so I do have to fix-before-parse. I was hoping this would somewhat common and find some workaround online, but nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Well, JAXB is just following the constraints of XML.  If there is no space it will not validate.  Maybe turn off validation?  It might work through it.

Comment: don't think its related to validation, its the malformed xml that is the problem here